# Quels participes passés se prononcent différemment selon le genre ?

Tags: prononciation, genre, participe-passé

Quand on utilise le passé composé, il faut parfois accorder le participe passé. Vraiment, quand on parle, je pense qu'il n'y a pas besoin de penser à cette règle, parce que, pour la plupart des mots, toutes les formes ne sont pas distinguées sauf dans l'orthographe.

Donc, dans

> je l'ai vu(e), parlé(e)(s), etc.,

ce n'est pas possible entendre une différence.

En fait, j'ai trouvé seulement 3 or 4 verbes qui font exception : les verbes qui terminent avec -indre comme atteindre.

1. Est-ce-que il y a des autres verbes (ou catégories des verbes) comme ça ?
2. C'est très grave si on fait une erreur de genre ou nombre quand on utilise ces mots (en langue orale) ?

Comment: Suivant l'accent, un e muet après une voyelle peut s'entendre clairement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il faut distinguer :

- l'accord du féminin : ajout d'un *e* qui est muet sauf quand il est précédé d'une consonne.
- l'accord du pluriel : ajout d'un *s* qu'on ne peut entendre que si on fait la liaison avec le mot suivant.

Statistiquement on entendra plus facilement un accord féminin qui suit une consonne et qui se fait spontanément, que l'accord du pluriel qui ne se fait pratiquement jamais, et je n'ai aucun exemple en tête où il soit obligatoire (ce qui ne veut pas dire que ce ne soit pas possible, bien sûr.)

Les verbes du [premier groupe](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premi%C3%A8re_conjugaison#Participe_Pass.C3.A9) ont un participe passé qui se termine au masculin par un *é*,  et on n'entend jamais le *e* du féminin.

Les verbes du [deuxième groupe](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuxi%C3%A8me_conjugaison#Participe_Pass.C3.A9) ont un participe passé qui se termine au masculin par un *i*, et on n'entend jamais le *e* du féminin.

Les seuls verbes pour lesquels on est susceptible d'entendre la marque du féminin au participe passé sont ceux du [troisième groupe](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugaison_des_verbes_du_troisi%C3%A8me_groupe#Participe_Pass.C3.A9) 
qui se terminent au masculin par une consonne, c'est à dire :

> - Participes passés terminés en s (-is, -os ou -us). Ce sont ceux des verbes  *absoudre, acquérir, asseoir, circoncire, clore, conquérir, dissoudre, enquérir, inclure, mettre, occire, prendre*, ainsi que les verbes de leurs familles :
>
>   - *Acquis ; conquis ; enquis ; requis ; circoncis ; mis ; occis ; pris ; sis… Clos… Absous ; dissous ; inclus*...
> - Participes passés terminés en t (-ait, -int, -it, -ort, -ert…). Ce sont ceux :
>
>   - De quelques verbes terminés en -ir (*couvrir, offrir, mourir, ouvrir, souffrir*) :
>       *Couvert ; offert ; mort ; ouvert ; souffert*.
>   - Des verbes en terminés -indre et en -uire (sauf *luire* et *nuire*) :
>           *Craint ; joint ; peint… ; cuit…*
>   - De quelques autres verbes en -re (*confire, dire, écrire, frire, faire, traire*) :
>           *Confit ; dit ; écrit ; frit ; fait ; trait*.
>
> Source [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugaison_des_verbes_du_troisi%C3%A8me_groupe#Participe_Pass.C3.A9)

Ces chansons je les ai **chantées avec** ferveur.
Habituel :  /ʃɑ̃.teavek/
Peut se dire :  /ʃɑ̃.tezavek/

Il a été **conquis**.
/kɔ̃.ki/

Il l'a **conquise** de haute lutte.
/kɔ̃.kiz/

Il les a **conquises** avec beaucoup de difficulté.
/kɔ̃.kza.vɛk/
La liaison du pluriel absorbe celle du féminin.

Ce travail je l'ai **fait** en vitesse.
/fɛ/
Le participe passé est au masculin, pas de liaison entre le *t* de *fait* et la voyelle qui débute le mot suivant.

L'étoile je l'ai **faite avec** du carton.
/fɛtavek/
L'exemple précédent me fait dire que c'est plutôt le *e* du féminin qu'on entend que la liaison avec le mot suivant.

Les étoiles je les ai **faites avec** du carton.
Habituel : /fɛtavek/
Peut se dire : /fɛtzavek/

Ces paroles ont été **dites en** public.
Habituel : /ditɑ̃py.blik/
Peut se dire : /ditzɑ̃py.blik/

Comment: Dans certains accents, il peut y avoir une différence de durée entre "é" et "ée" ou "i" et "ie", n'est-ce pas? Comme en [Belgique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Français_de_Belgique#La_prononciation_et_les_accents)

Comment: @sumelic Je n'en sais rien. Il y a quelques Belges sur French Language, ils pourraient peut-être le dire ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Oui, il y en a ; par exemple :

   - *prendre* (*pris*, *prise*, *pris*, *prises*) et ses dérivés
   - *mettre* (*mis*, *mise*, *mis*, *mises*) et ses dérivés
   - *maudire* (*maudit*, *maudite*, *maudits*, *maudites*)
2. Non. Dans le langage courant, cet accord ne se fait que rarement.

Answer (score 3):

Une ressource utile: *[The Agreement of the Past Participle in Spoken French, as a Sociolinguistic Variable: Production and Perception](https://ore.exeter.ac.uk/repository/bitstream/handle/10871/14724/D-Gaucher_APP-spoken-French.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y),* par Damien Fabien Rémi Gaucher (September 2013, University of Exeter Ph.D. thesis)

Gaucher dit que les participes passés qui terminent par une voyelle + un e muet peuvent se prononcer avec des voyelles longues distinctives dans certains accents de la Normandie, de la Belgique or de la Suisse. (Voir "[Français de Belgique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_de_Belgique#La_prononciation_et_les_accents)", Wikipédia)

Il y a un tableau qui présente certains mots notés par Eugène Tanase dans  "L'accord du participe passé dans le français oral" (1976).

La description (en anglais):

> Table 2.2 represents Tanase's typology of these forms. In this classification, the verbs are ranked by frequency. The category FF1
>   corresponds to the *Français Fondamental 1 (FF 1)* and englobes the 1500 most common words, and *Français Fondamental 2 (FF2)*
>   the following 1700 words; the third category includes less frequent words, and the fourth category the least frequent ones.

(p. 57)

Le tableau:

> Table 2.2: Inventory of the verb forms ending with a consonant
>
> FF 1
>
> - /z/ asseoir, mettre, permettre, promettre,remettre, prendre, apprendre,  comprendre, reprendre
> - /t/ conduire,  construire,  couvrir, cuire, dire, écrire, éteindre, faire,  mourir,  offrir,  ouvrir, peindre, plaindre
>
> FF 2
>
> - /z/ admettre, commettre, soumettre, entreprendre, surprendre
> - /t/ atteindre,  craindre,  découvrir,
>     décrire, défaire, frire, inscrire, interdire, redire, refaire, satisfaire,
>     souffrir
>
> FF 3
>
> - /z/ acquérir, conquérir, s'éprendre, se méprendre, compremettre [sic: *ça veut dire* compromettre], émettre, omettre, transmettre
> - /t/ extraire, instruire, soustraire
>
> FF 4
>
> - /z/ enquérir, requérir, clore, éclore,
>     forclore, inclure, démettre, entremettre,  déprendre,  désapprendre, seoir, messeoir
> - /t/ absoudre, astreindre, ceindre,
>     confire, contraindre, contredire,
>     contrefait, dissoudre, distraire,
>     dédire,  déduire,  dépeindre,
>     détruire, empreindre, enduire,
>     enfreindre, épreindre, étreindre,
>     feindre, forfait, geindre, joindre, maudire, médire, oindre,
>     poindre,  prédire,  ratteindre,
>     recouvrir, rempreindre, repeindre, restreindre, surfait, teindre,
>     traire

(p. 58)

Ce n'est pas très grave si on fait une "erreur" de genre ou nombre d'un participe passé en langue orale. La situation se complique sous l'effet de plusieurs facteurs, mais en général, les francophones ne font pas toujours cet accord.

Comment: Je ne peux rien dire sur le français de Belgique mais vivant en Normandie depuis très longtemps avant la date de publication de cette thèse, je n'ai jamais entendu de participe passé se terminant par un e muet prononcé avec une voyelle longue distinctive, même par des personnes très âgées qui vivent isolées des zones urbaines. Je doute donc fort de la fiabilité de l'ouvrage cité.

Answer (score 2):

2. Si. Dans le langage courant, cet accord doit se faire et il a d'ailleurs des répercussions socioculturelles qu'on ne peut éluder, même si on peut le critiquer : 
   Selon le contexte, dire "je l'ai pris" à la place de "je l'ai prise" (en parlant d'un objet féminin) peut-être disqualifiant, pas au café entre amis bien sûr, mais dans un contexte plus formel/professionnel.

D'autant qu'à la forme passive, le participe passé féminin s'entendra toujours, peu importe le registre de langue : 
- La messe est dite 
- Les carottes sont cuites 
- La table est mise
- Par qui donc l'Amérique aurait-elle été "découverte" ?

L'accord du participe passé est sans aucun doute ce qu'il y a de plus compliqué en français, mais on ne peut prendre la liberté de faire l'impasse dessus, à moins de dégrader la langue que l'on emploie.

Comment: Cela dépend peut-être d’où se situe « chez vous », si un particularisme local a rendu fréquente une forme qui partout ailleurs dans l’espace francophone sera considérée comme erronée : « répond » sera ainsi toujours une forme conjuguée du verbe et non un participe passé, « répondu » étant la seule forme admise. Donc oui, utiliser l’un pour l’autre sera encore plus disqualifiant qu’oublier l’accord du participe passé.

Comment: Chez nous c'est au Québec. C'est une erreur assurément. Quand on me pose la question du genre « est-ce qu'il t'a répond (sic) ? », je regarde mon interlocuteur parce que j'interprète son participe comme un impératif, genre _réponds-moi s'il t'a (répondu)_. J'ai du m'habituer à traiter cette erreur comme si de rien n'était. C'est loufoque. Merci !